# Recover accidentally deleted function that is loaded in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I was editing my `.bashrc` file (actually a file sourced in there) and added a bunch of functions. I track my home directory in git, but I accidentally did a hard reset before even staging the changes.

So I lost all I added, and I really need to get that back since I spent a lot of time on that.

My terminal has the functions loaded though - I can call them. So I thought to myself is it possible to still recover this? Is this being written somewhere else on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's very simple. Just had to call this in my current session:

```
typeset -f
```

Turns out typeset is obsolete (run help typeset). Call this instead:

```
declare -f
```

I hope it helps someone - I got really scared.

Comment: `typeset` is obsolete, use `declare` instead.